# Does TensorFlow Lite not support GRU layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I've create an inference model defined below;

```
def get_model():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input((543, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
    vector = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(inputs)
    vector = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(vector)
    vector = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu")(vector)
    vector = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(vector)
    vector = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(vector) # Add first GRU layer
    vector = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32)(vector) # Add second GRU layer
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation="softmax")(vector)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
        metrics=[
            "accuracy", 
            tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=5, name="top-5-accuracy"),
            tf.keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=10, name="top-10-accuracy")
        ]
    )
    return model

def get_inference_model(model):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input((543, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name="inputs")
    x = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(inputs), tf.zeros_like(inputs), inputs)
    x = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=0, keepdims=True)
    for i in range(1, len(model.layers)):
        x = model.layers[i](x)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Activation(activation="linear", name="outputs")(x)
    inference_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output) 
    inference_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=["accuracy"])
    return inference_model


inference_model = get_inference_model(get_model())
```

This model works fine, about 40% validation accuracy. However, I need to convert it to a `.tfLite` model. When I do this I get the below warning:

> WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as _update_step_xla, gru_cell_4_layer_call_fn, gru_cell_4_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, gru_cell_5_layer_call_fn, gru_cell_5_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses while saving (showing 5 of 5). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.

Most topics on this warning say to ignore it, but if I use the TfLite model for predictions it has very low accuracy, nowhere near 40%. My guess is that TfLite doesn't support GRU layers, but I'm trying to confirm that is the issue. This is the code I use to convert to TFLite:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(inference_model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
model_path = "model.tflite"
# Save the model.
with open(model_path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

Is there a way to convert this model to a TfLite model while keeping the GRU layers?

Comment: Please add your model definition so that others can reproduce.

Comment: Added. I create the model that I used for training. Then I create an inference model to predict.

Comment: what's the tf.__version__?